# Python any() + generator expression

Tags: performance, python-2.7, for-loop, generator, any

According to the blog post [here](http://jjinux.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/python-any-generator-expression.html), an any() + generator expression should run quicker than a for loop, and it seems like his reasoning makes sense.

But I've tried to use this method (albeit on some other function), but it seems to take a longer time to run than an explicit for loop.

```
def with_loop(a, b):
    for x in xrange(1, b):
        if x * a % b == 1: return True
    return False

def with_generator(a, b):
    return any(x * a % b == 1 for x in xrange(1, b))
```

Basically the code loops through all the numbers from 1 to *b* to find whether the number *a* has a modular inverse.

The times I got from running the functions are:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer as T
>>> T(lambda : with_generator(100, 300)).repeat(number = 100000)
[3.4041796334919923, 3.6303230626526215, 3.6714475531563266]
>>> T(lambda : with_loop(100, 300)).repeat(number = 100000)
[2.1977450660490376, 2.2083902291327604, 2.1905292602997406]
>>> T(lambda : with_generator(101, 300)).repeat(number = 100000)
[1.213779524696747, 1.2228346702509043, 1.2216941170634072]
>>> T(lambda : with_loop(101, 300)).repeat(number = 100000)
[0.7431202233722161, 0.7444361146951906, 0.7525384471628058]
```

with_generator(100,300) returns False and with_generator(101,300) returns True.

It seems that with_generator always takes a longer time to run than with_loop. Is there any reason for this?

EDIT:
Is there any other shorter or more elegant way of rewriting with_loop so that we achieve similar or better performance? Thanks!

Comment: Further to the answer by User below, are there any other "more elegant" or shorter way of writing the code above, but still achieving a similar/better speed as with_loop?

Answer (score 7):

**Context**

I think that

> any() + generator expression should run quicker than a for loop

means that `any` does not generate all values but a loop does:

```
>>> T(lambda : any([x * 101 % 300 == 1 for x in xrange(1, 300)])).repeat(number = 100000)
[5.7612644951345935, 5.742304846931542, 5.746804810873488]
>>> T(lambda : any(x * 101 % 300 == 1 for x in xrange(1, 300))).repeat(number = 100000)
[2.1652204281427814, 2.1640463131248886, 2.164674290446399]
```

So the quote does not mean that a loop can never achieve the performance of a generator.

The quote means that a loop usually generates all elements and any does not use all of them and a generator only generates the elements that any uses.

Your function `with_loop` is equivalent to the generator. So you can not expect a different behaviour.

To put it more clearly: `any(loop)` is slower than `any(generator)` because the loop generates everything. Your `with_loop` is equivalent to `any(generator)` and not to `any(loop)`.

**Original Question**

```
>>> profile.run("""T(lambda : with_loop(101, 300)).repeat(number = 100000)""")
         600043 function calls (600040 primitive calls) in 6.133 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(append)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(clock)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(disable)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(enable)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(globals)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(hasattr)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(isenabled)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(isinstance)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(range)
        1    0.005    0.005    0.005    0.005 :0(setprofile)
   300000    0.579    0.000    5.841    0.000 <string>:1(<lambda>)
      4/1    0.000    0.000    6.128    6.128 <string>:1(<module>)
   300000    5.262    0.000    5.262    0.000 <string>:1(with_loop)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.133    6.133 profile:0(T(lambda : with_loop(101, 300)).repeat(number = 100000))
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:121(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        3    0.000    0.000    6.128    2.043 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.128    6.128 timeit.py:201(repeat)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:94(_template_func)
        3    0.287    0.096    6.128    2.043 timeit.py:96(inner)


>>> profile.run("""T(lambda : with_generator(101, 300)).repeat(number = 100000)""")
         31500043 function calls (31500040 primitive calls) in 70.531 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   300000   30.898    0.000   67.590    0.000 :0(any)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(append)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(clock)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(disable)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(enable)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(globals)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(hasattr)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(isenabled)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(isinstance)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(range)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
   300000    0.667    0.000   70.222    0.000 <string>:1(<lambda>)
      4/1    0.000    0.000   70.531   70.531 <string>:1(<module>)
   300000    1.629    0.000   69.555    0.000 <string>:6(with_generator)
 30600000   37.027    0.000   37.027    0.000 <string>:7(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000   70.531   70.531 profile:0(T(lambda : with_generator(101, 300)).repeat(number = 100000))
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:121(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        3    0.000    0.000   70.531   23.510 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.000    0.000   70.531   70.531 timeit.py:201(repeat)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:94(_template_func)
        3    0.309    0.103   70.531   23.510 timeit.py:96(inner)
```

To call the generator every time, 30600000 times, seems to be much slower than just a for loop.

If you know how many elements exist in a list then you can write this:

```
l[0] * 101 % 300 == 1 or l[1] * 101 % 300 == 1 or l[2] * 101 % 300 == 1 or ....
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I didn't know that any() will call the generator so many times! Anyway, is there any other "more elegant" or shorter way of writing with_loop (using the same idea), like how with_generator is written in a single line? While maintaining/improving the speed, of course.

Comment: I think there is no functional way in Python to write this for loop differently and equally fast. If you know the number of elements you coud also use `...[0]... or ...[1]... or ...[2]...` But apart from that I think there is no way.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the ...[0]... part? I don't really get it. Thanks!

Comment: Done. It is in the answer. I really should have written a bit more.

Comment: "means that any does not generate all values but a loop does:" By "loop", did you mean **list comprehension**?